# Download tracker with .htaccess but without redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to execute some php codes to track file downloads when some one requests to access to my files (mp4 files for example)
I know there are ways like redirecting to a php file, then increasing the counter and after that using `readfile()` or redirecting again to the main file but for some reasons these are not good solutions for me.

Redirect is not OK because when I do this download attribute of my anchor element is useless and the file is going to be downloaded with the original name

and `readfile()` is not my choice because my files are very large and I want a solution without any overhead for my server

Comment: "for some reasons these are not good solutions for me". Questions with such a way of reasoning are really annoying. Either you have a reasons, then share it, or you don't. Don't ask in riddles if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha , I modified my question

Comment: It is unclear what the issue here is. `readfile()` does not create any real "overhead on your server" compared to directly referring to the file. In both cases the files content is read in chunks into a buffer and posted to the client. Anyway, if I get that right, then you ultimately want to serve the file directly via apache. This will be a tricky thing and I do not see any reason for that. You could try to take a look at using an internal rewrite rule based on a rewrite map which knows about all downloadable files. But as said: looks like you try to solve an issue that does not exist.

Comment: You could rely on Apache logs: http://serverfault.com/questions/110186/how-to-get-apache-download-counts-by-week

Comment: @arkascha, try to  readfile() a large file, you will understand that php will try to load all of it to the memory

Comment: Thank you @Bogdan, It's a very useful idea, But I want to handle the reports inside my application with the titles, descriptions and etc and its not enough file's per name access count, so I should store them in my DB

Comment: @MahyarDamavand I can only imagine that this is the case if you have created an output buffer. Then of course things will be kept in that buffer. Without output buffer the payload is _not_ loaded fully into memory. But even _if_ that were the case, then it would be 3 lines of code to implement the desired strategy: open file, read and write a chunk in a loop, close file.

Comment: @arkascha, Unfortunately  `readfile()` returns memory usage error even if I don't use output buffer. I tried the other strategy and although there is not any error but the download takes about 14 seconds to start for a filesize of 80MB. most of my files are larger than that.

Answer (score 1):

If with `.htaccess` you rewrite the link, the original link in the browser do not change.

You can rewrite all `.mp4` files with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.mp4)$ /tracker.php?f=$1 [L]
```

After your root `tracker.php` receives the link to count (in `f`), download and send.
Without link change in the browser url.

Comment: Thank you @croises , But how should I download and send it?

Comment: I told you that I can't use readfile() or fread() because of **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XXX bytes exhausted** and I have very large files witch is not well-advised to change the value